# How to query memSQL with Scala?

Tags: scala, jdbc, singlestore

I'm trying to query MemSql using Scala, with not much success. So far, the closest I got was [MemSql Spark Connector](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector), though it requires MemSql configurations in Spark configurations, which is not possible in my case.

I'm looking for something simple, like Clojure's [yeSql](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql). As I'm quite new to using JDBC, any additional information will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Scala runs on the JVM, and Scala and Java classes can be freely mixed. That being said, the MemSQL Spark Connector leverages `mysql-connector-java` (seen in the [`build.sbt`](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector/blob/master/build.sbt#L76)). You can download `mysql-connector-java` from many places, including [MySQL's website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).